# My CSS works well in localhost but breaks when I publish my application online?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

here the livepage:

https://horizon-coding.herokuapp.com/portfolio/pizza

my suggestions:

- ***Im using a custom server in NextJS, maybe it influences the result?***
- other hint please, do you think the order of my CSS rule can play a role here? Because the rules of my stylesheet in local is no the same order than online. So maybe some rules can be overwritten. *By `order of CSS` rule I m talking about the the rule's scopes `.divA{establish some rules here at a specific position in the stylesheet, top of stylesheet or bottom of stylesheet}` above the simple specific rules `font.. margin.. etc.`*
- it can be webpack, alterations between development environment and distribution environment.

***the fact is that I do nothing between development mode and production mode but just run yarn build => leading to next build. So all the process is automatized. So why it would work in local and after the build, it would break?*** *I have compared a specific sequence of the two stylesheets relative to the navigation sidebar °which break with blue font in production mode° in my test, and the result is the following: Content 100% matched*

Here two snapshots figuring the difference between local and distribution modes.

Local mode:

[image]

Built -production- mode:

[image]

I have built a website with NextJS and ReactJS. When I'm working on localhost the CSS attaches well  °built code or just development mode's code work well both° my application but when working online it just breaks and is displayed on some part, and fails to be displayed on other parts.

What are the possibilities of trouble here please? I can t figure out what is going on, my CSS is well, even my JS is well, just two little

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: might be related to path issue. Check in console r u getting any 404 error

Comment: okay I wiil get an eye but meanwhile I have a question please, if it is 404 error why it would work locally but not onlinely?

Comment: In Localhost, your root directory will be '/'. But in Server, it will be inside some Content or www folder as per web server

Comment: thanks for your answers, so far when it seems the CSS is loaded but partially, some part -font and color for example- are loaded, the other part break as if they was absent -some margin, some font also, etc.-. I am in presence of a partial styling

Comment: Im using a custom server in NextJS, maybe it influences the result?

Comment: _"other hint please, do you think the order of my CSS rule can play a role here? Because the rules of my stylesheet in local is no the same order than online. So maybe some rules can be overwritten."_  Yes, order matters in CSS.  This could be the issue.  The symptom here would be some styling being incorrect, though-- if styling seems as though it is completely _absent_, that would indicate a different kind of problem.

Comment: The easiest way to get help would be to show the website, so we can examine the code. Otherwise we can only make guesses.

Comment: https://horizon-coding.herokuapp.com/portfolio/pizza here captain, my website is not very finished, I am new in the field. But here the page you have asked, you can admire the difference with my localhost, I have put some edits on my post

Comment: Try examining elements in the web inspector to compare what css rules are being utilized by the elements. You can tell a lot through that. Order in css certainly matters, so it's best to have your production code as similar to your working development code as possible.

Comment: to evacuate ambiguity, when I am saying `order of my CSS rule` I m talking about the the rule's scopes, for example: `.divA{establish some rules here at a specific position in the stylesheet, top of stylesheet or bottom of stylesheet}` above the simple specific rules `font.. margin.. etc.`

Comment: @GrantNoe thanks for your answer, have you  advices  or resources about order in CSS rules?

Comment: @Webwoman these links should help a lot, but I think the key in your case is to just keep things in the same order as the working version. You most likely already possess the solution. https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/ |||||   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @GrantNoe thanks a lot, I have an another question please about the order, the fact is that I do nothing between development mode and production mode but just run `yarn build` => leading to `next build`. So all the process is automatized. Maybe there is some rules about code building than can explain the shifting, that why I have put webpack in my hints on my post.

Comment: @Webwoman someone else will answer that better than me since I don’t utilize yarn enough to provide a nuanced answer.

Comment: @GrantNoe okay thanks for having take from  your time to assist

Comment: Perhaps the menu font is only available locally, but not when you upload the site? So it is picking a substitute? In that case upload the font and link to it in CSS, or link to it as a URL in Google font library. 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will double check again, the fact is that the margin and the text for the `Gustoso for the adventurer` part would be missing also, so there is an another break somewhere probably

Comment: does it have access to the actual font file?

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the hint yes it have access to the font I want to use. Just seems TimeSS override the font I want to use here, when I deselect TimeSS I have the font  I want, seems there is a problem of CSS overriding, at lease in part, that would explain why even in dev mode I have to reload the page to have the CSS I intend to build.

Comment: better double check your CSS file then